# VS Code 1.13.1 - Git SCM Issue

Tags: git, cordova

I just installed VS Code 1.13.1 over the last few days and have been able to get everything working to build a Cordova application. But, i have tried to install git and git cli. I'm not sure but i might have messed up the built-in Git SCM. I don't see any Git SCM in the more menu. Please help!

Note: I tried to install git/git cli from the integrated terminal. Under Extersions - category:"SCM Providers" @sort:installs there are only VS Team Serivces, Perforce for VS Code and Hg.

Comment: You could have just hidden it. If you right click on the left-bar (The activity bar) in the blank area, can you check "Source Control" to make it re-appear?

Comment: I don't see how to add it back. I don't have a SCM for GIT. Seems like if this is the default there should be a way to add it back or turn it on. I can switch to either of the following extensions; VS team services, Preforce for VS Code, or Hg SCM. No Git.  I'm going to install this on my laptop at home to see if I had Git SCM by default on a new install.